# Error in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I saw [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE7ezYCTPe4) [ 10:00 ]
to start create a 2d game in Java and I tried using the code he used in the video and I get error and I don't know how to fix him.

```
package me.Kenig.game2d;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 160;
    public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH/12*9;
    public static final int SCALE = 3;
    public static final String NAME = "Game";

    private JFrame frame; // error

    public Game(){
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
    }

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // error


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)You never instantiate your JFrame

Try

```
this.frame = new JFrame();
```

in your constructor

2)Another problem :

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

is not in the right place : it should be in a method. You should also prefer `WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` rather than `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.

3)You should also call `frame.pack()` to force the frame to adapt its size to fit with the size of its contained elements.

Here is a piece of code :

```
public Game(){
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
  setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));

  //Not really necessary because of frame.pack()
  //setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));

  //You should add some elements here
  JPanel panel=new JPanel();
  panel.add(new JTextField(10));

  frame.add(panel);

  //Forces the frame to take the minimum-size to contain its elements
  frame.pack();
  frame.show();
}
```

You should look at [Visual guide to Swing components](http://dimson.hd.free.fr/sun_original_cours/docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/compWin.html) to see which component exist and how they behave.

You should also have a look at [visual guide to layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to understand how your components are placed

Good luck :)

Comment: Adding the line does effect this but adding errors all over the page.
I know it's something stupid but I am new in this..

Comment: Great, I fixed it.
I have another problem with this line:
private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
private int[] pixels =((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData(); // err
DataBufferInt cannot be resolved to a variable